# Birth season paradox

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The birthday paradox is a surprising result of probability. Suppose you randomly chose $23$ people and put them in a room. Then there would be a good chance $\big($greater than $\frac{1}{2}\big)$ that two of those people share a birthday (even though there are $365$ days in the year).

What about birth seasons (spring, summer, fall, winter)? Suppose you randomly chose $3$ people and put them in a room. Then is it true that there would be a greater than $\frac{1}{2}$ chance that two of them share a birth season?
[image]

Note: Birth seasons do not all have the exact same likelihood. However, their likelihoods are close enough that you can assume they are equal for this problem.

Comment: Not so surprising if you think of the number of couples that makes.

Comment: @JomsJosephLeelin By the [pigeonhole principle](https://brilliant.org/wiki/pigeonhole-principle-definition/), it is **guaranteed** that with $5$ people. $2$ of them share a birth season. It's not unreasonable that there is a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance for $3$ people.

Comment: The [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Near_matches) $1 - \frac{(m-nk-1)!}{(m^{n-1}(m-n(k+1)))!}$ gives the probability of a finding a pair in a group of $n$ people, separated by $k$ calendar days, with $m$ equally likely dates. Substituting in $n=3, k=0, m=4$ gives $\frac{5}{8}$ by [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+-+(4+-+3*0+-+1)!%2F(4%5E(3-1)+*+(4+-+3(0%2B1))!)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider just $1$ person in the room, and then a $2nd$ person enters. The probability that the second person has a different birth season than the first is $\frac{3}{4}.$ The probability that these people share a birth season is therefore $1-\frac{3}{4}=\frac{1}{4}.$

Now suppose that a 3rd person entered the room. He would have a $\frac{2}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$ chance to have a different birth season from the first two.

Now consider the probability of both these events happening (first two people's birth seasons different, $3rd$ person's birth season different as well): $ \frac{3}{4} \times \frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{8}.$

Since the probability that the first three people's birth seasons are different is $\frac{3}{8},$ the probability that the first three people have at least a pair that share a birth season is $1-\frac{3}{8}=\frac{5}{8}.$